# How do identity provider like Auth0 and Cognito authenticate requests from frontend to backend?

Tags: authentication, oauth, authorization, amazon-cognito, auth0

I have an application that is an angular web app that calls to a backend API in Java.

I will like to use third party services like Auth0 or Cognito, the only problem is, I am having a hard time understanding overall architecture of how they work. I have read through documentations but could not find answers.

Specifically want I want to know is this.

Do my application need to make a request to Auth0/Cognito on each user request after authentication?

I understand that there is a authentication part, where my app redirects to Auth0/Cognito where the user can sign in. And I understand that after this sign in is done, I can some form of access-code from Auth0/Cognito.

Ok so authentication is done, and my user needs to use the frontend of my app to interact with the backend of my app. The question is, do the frontend needs to send whatever code they got after authentication, and conversely do my backend now need to call Auth0/Cognito to validate what they got from the front end? And do I need to do this for every request (it looks like I will have to, if I want to trust what the frontend is sending)

If I need to check on Auth0 on every request won't that affect performance? Since my app will be essentially making a request across network boundaries to an external system on every request?

Answer (score 0):

I can explain how this happens in the case of Auth0, but Cognito will not be much different.

First, both your front-end and back-end applications must be properly configured to talk to the Auth0 platform.

After user authentication, your front-end receives an ID token and an access token. The ID token proves user authentication and optionally contains user profile data. The access token authorizes your front-end application to call your back-end. It is in JWT format and can also contain specific permissions. All requests from your front-end to your protected backend must include the access token.

The first time your backend receives a request from your frontend, it contacts Auth0 to retrieve and cache the signing public key and other data. This stuff is needed to validate the access token it receives from the frontend.

From now on, your backend doesn't need to contact Auth0 again (until the cache expires or something changes at the configuration level). All subsequent requests can be validated locally using the cached stuff.

I hope this helps to get a high-level understanding of the behavior.